# How to do secrets management in hugging face inference endpoints?

Tags: huggingface, inference

I'm deploying llama 2 in hugging face inference endpoints. Though to do so I need my token to get the base model weights. I could not find anywhere documentation how to manage this secrets. Any directions?

Comment: from a quick search on `huggingface.co/docs` seems like they only support secrets in `spaces` and from the inference endpoint i just deployed, there are no relevant settings in the web gui during endpoint creation.